# Sampling unsigned integer texture data in a shader

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, unsigned-integer

I want to render a unsigned integer texture with fragment shader using following code:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8UI, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

and part of the fragment shader code:

```
#version 330
uniform usampler2D tex;
void main(void){
    vec3 vec_tex;
    vec_tex = (texture(tex), TexCoordOut).r
}
```

It is written in ***OpenGL Programming Guide***, that if I want to receive integers in shader, then I should use an integer sampler type, an integer internal format, and an integer external format and type. Here is us `GL_R8UI` as internal format, `GL_RED_INTEGER` as external format, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as data type. I also use `usampler2D` in shader. But when the program starts to render the file, always got error ***implicit cast from "int" to "uint"***. It seems that the texture data is stored as int, and the unsigned sampler can not convert that. But I did use `GL_R8UI` as internal format, so the texture data should be stored as unsigned. why the unsigned sampler only get signed int? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You know that `vec3` is floating-point, right? If you want to store the results of fetching from a `usampler2D`, you should probably use `uvec3`. Even then, if this is literally your shader it should be generating a more serious error than that. `texture (...)` requires texture coordinates and `TexCoordOut` is not even defined.

Answer (score 0):

The texture function call is not correct, secondly the texture function returns float values which needs to handled in shader by dividing the RGBA components by 255.0 (as you use GL_R8UI) and return and fragment color output.

```
uniform usampler2D tex;
out uvec3 OutColor;
void main(void){
    uvec3 vec_tex;
    vec_tex = texture(tex, TexCoordOut)
    OutColor = vec3(float(vec_tex.r)/255, float(vec_tex.g)/255, float(vec_tex.b)/255)
}
```